# Check application status and proceed when it avilible

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I need to check if the application is available (the application is started via child_process node API), the time until the application is up can be changed 2 - 30 sec. if the application is not available I need to stop the process with  process.exit(1);

I think about checking the application port if its open with
https://github.com/baalexander/node-portscanner

```
portscanner.checkPortStatus(3000, '127.0.0.1', function(error, status) {
  // Status is 'open' if currently in use or 'closed' if available
  console.log(status)
})
```

lets say I've the application port(as param) how should I do it **nicely** (with Timeout?) every 100 ms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Javascript timing events: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

You can use setInterval(function, milliseconds) to execute your portscanning every 100ms but be careful: the shortest the interval the closer you are to a danger area as the port scanning will consume resourses from the scanning machine and from the scanned machine.

See the example from W3S below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

  function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your case it could be (if checkPortStatus is what you want ;) ):

```
var myTimer = setInterval(scan, 100);
function scan() {
   portscanner.checkPortStatus(3000, '127.0.0.1', function(error, status) {
     // Status is 'open' if currently in use or 'closed' if available
     console.log(status)
     if (status == 'closed') {
       clearInterval(myTimer);
       doYourThing();
     }
   });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I need :) this should be a recourseive call to it, can you provide example ?

Comment: @shopiaT setInterval calls the function every X milliseconds, until you cancel it so you would check the desired port every 100 miliseconds.
It is not clear to me yet why it wouldn't solve your problem.

Comment: I've updated the answer with examples, please let me know if this is what you need.